# How to set size of a dynamically created TextBox in VB.Net 2017 Form

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am trying to set the size of dynamically created TextBox on Button click event.
But after after mentioning the size there is no effect in size. Kindly guide me where I'm wrong.

Here is my small code

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Dim tb As New TextBox
        tb.Name = "TextBox" + number.ToString

        tb.Size = New Size(150, 1500)

        Label17.Text = tb.Height 'Showing 20 

        tb.Location = New Point(TextBox3.Location.X, TextBox3.Location.Y + 35)
        Me.Controls.Add(tb)
    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `TextBox.Multiline` set to `True` at some point?

Comment: Set `tb.Multiline = true` to allow the textbox span multiple lines.